# Why does my fetch request gives no output in android, when its working fine in web [REACT-NATIVE with EXPO]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have this code, for registering user, on web version its working, but on android via expo app, its not working

my code

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import {
    Image,
    ImageBackground,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

const SignUp = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
    const dev_url = Constants.expoConfig.extra.devBackendUrl;
    const prod_url = Constants.expoConfig.extra.prodBackendUrl;
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? dev_url : prod_url;

    // console.log(env);

    const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(email, username, password);
        if (!email || !username || !password) {
            alert("Please fill all the fields");
            return;
        }
        try {
            console.log("1", env + "/register");
            const res = await fetch(env + "/register", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ email, username, password }),
            });
            console.log("2");
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <ImageBackground
            source={{
                uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567360425618-1594206637d2",
            }}
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
            <View className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
                <Image
                    className="w-32 h-32 rounded-full"
                    source={{
                        uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605125207928-0b878b4a6570",
                    }}
                />
                <Text className="text-white text-2xl my-10 font-bold">
                    SIGN UP
                </Text>
                <View className="w-2/3 my-10">
                    <View className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center space-y-10 w-full">
                        <TextInput
                            type="email"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            name="email"
                            id="email"
                            className="bg-white rounded-xl py-2 px-7 w-full"
                            value={email}
                            onChangeText={setEmail}
                            required
                            autoFocus
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            name="username"
                            id="username"
                            className="bg-white rounded-xl py-2 px-7 w-full"
                            value={username}
                            onChangeText={setUsername}
                            required
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            type="password"
                            secureTextEntry
                            placeholder="Password"
                            name="password"
                            id="password"
                            className="bg-white rounded-xl py-2 px-7 w-full"
                            value={password}
                            onChangeText={setPassword}
                            required
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            className="bg-[#00FF19] rounded-xl py-2 px-7 w-full"
                            onPress={handleSignUp}
                        >
                            <Text className="text-black text-center text-xl font-bold">
                                SUBMIT
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    className="bg-[#0047FF] rounded-xl py-2 px-7 w-2/3"
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
                >
                    <Text className="text-white text-center text-xl font-bold">
                        LOGIN
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
            </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    );
};

export default SignUp;
```

this is my nodejs backend code
https://pastebin.com/KK2i3jak

I with a lot of difficulty saw the network request using Reactotron
here it is

````
# Request

### Endpoint

`POST` http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:8000/register

### Duration

`31630` ms

### Data Sent

```json
{
  "email": "Jdjddj",
  "username": "Jddjjr",
  "password": "jrjdsjj"
}
````

#### Headers

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| content-type | application/json |
| access-control-allow-origin | * |

## Response

#### Data Received

```json
 skipped
```